# How to send data from an html table to nodejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to send data from a table using jquery to get the values of the table but not send them by POST method in node js, for the moment I only show them in an alert, but how pass the jquery data to nodejs app.post('/send_data');

```
$("#btnEnviarDatos").click(function () {
$("#datatable-responsive tbody tr").each(function (index) {
    var campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6, campo7, campo8, campo9;
    $(this).children("td").each(function (index2) {
        switch (index2) {
            case 1:
            campo1 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 2:
            campo2 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 3:
            campo3 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 4:
            campo4 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 5:
            campo5 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 6:
            campo6 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 7:
            campo7 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 8:
            campo8 = $(this).text();
            break;
            case 9:
            campo9 = $(this).text();
            break;
        }
    });
    if(campo1!=undefined && campo2!=undefined && campo3!=undefined && campo4!=undefined && campo5!=undefined && campo6!=undefined && campo7!=undefined && campo8!=undefined && campo9!=undefined){
        alert(''+campo1 + ' - ' + campo2 + ' - ' + campo3+ ' - ' + campo4+ ' - ' + campo5+ ' - ' + campo6+ ' - ' + campo7+ ' - ' + campo8 + ' - ' + campo9);
    }         
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `JSON.stringify` 
Try that:

```
$('#btnEnviarDatos').click(function () {
  var data = { trs: [] };
  $('#datatable-responsive tbody tr').each(function (index) {
    var tr = {};
    $(this).children('td').each(function (index2) {
      tr['campo'+index2] = $(this).text();
    });
    data.trs.push(tr);
  });
  alert( JSON.stringify(data) );     
});
```